# rosmaster unresponsive

Tags: ros, rosmaster, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have a somewhat weird problem with rosmaster.
In certain situations rosmaster becomes completely unresponsive and reports 100% cpu usage.
The situation occurred in Electric both under Ubuntu Natty (2.6.38-13) and Oneiric (3.0.0-14) 64-bit.

An executable p (written in C++) subscribes and publishes to a single topic t and sends message every 100ms via rosudp. After about 10 seconds the executable calls ros::shutdown() and terminates.

Executables are started in the following pattern:

```
while(true) {
 for(i: 1..10) {
  for(j: 1..10) {
    Start p i-times in parallel.
    Wait for all processes to terminate
    Sleep(0.5s)
  }
 }
}
```

After about 300 runs through the innermost loop, rosmaster becomes unresponsive without error message.
Tools such as roswtf or rostopic fail to communicate with it and do not report any error.
Further, cpu usage of rosmaster climbs to 100% in top. This happens both if the nodes initialise ros with the AnonymousName init option or without.

Is there any suggested way to diagnose this problem? Is there an upper limit on the number of processes/nodes a roscore can manage?

Update:

The master.log contains many errors similar to the following:

```
[rosmaster.threadpool][ERROR] 2012-02-03 12:28:02,770: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/threadpool.py", line 218, in run
result = cmd(*args)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/master_api.py", line 189, in publisher_update_task
xmlrpcapi(api).publisherUpdate('/master', topic, pub_uris)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1575, in __request
verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
return self.parse_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1473, in parse_response
return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 793, in close
raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
Fault: <Fault -1: 'publisherUpdate: unknown method name'>
```

The log ends with the following error:

```
rosmaster.threadpool][ERROR] 2012-02-03 12:28:38,945: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/threadpool.py", line 218, in run
result = cmd(*args)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/master_api.py", line 189, in publisher_update_task
xmlrpcapi(api).publisherUpdate('/master', topic, pub_uris)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1575, in __request
verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1292, in single_request
self.send_content(h, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1439, in send_content
connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 951, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 811, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 773, in send
self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 754, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

The complete log is available at [http://das-lab.net/~cn/crash03022012-master.log.tar.gz](http://das-lab.net/%7Ecn/crash03022012-master.log.tar.gz)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12870/rosmaster-unresponsive/) by [RedundantEntry](https://answers.ros.org/users/1733/redundantentry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-02-07**:
FYI: still looking into this.  haven't been able to reproduce yet

**Comment by [RedundantEntry](https://answers.ros.org/users/1733/redundantentry/) on 2012-02-03**:
Sure! The complete log is available at [http://das-lab.net/~cn/crash03022012-master.log.tar.gz](http://das-lab.net/%7Ecn/crash03022012-master.log.tar.gz)

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-02-03**:
can you post the logfile from the master somewhere? (roscd log: look for master.log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer part of the question, a rosmaster should easily function with hundreds of nodes.  It does begin to perform worse if the nodes have bad connectivity as the master is required to contact nodes with updates.

The exceptions appear to be a red-herring. Because your node publishes and subscribes to the same topic, there's basically a race condition where the master informs the node that the subscriptions for a topic it subscribes to has changed -- the exception is printed just in case, but I don't think it's at the heart of the problem.

I attempted to write a test program that replicated your test node, but couldn't elicit the 100% CPU usage after 30 minutes of repeated running.  I would need your actual test code to proceed any further.

I made a minor tweak to the rosmaster code as I look back over it. I don't think it fixes your issue, but you're welcome to try:

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/changeset/16264

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0